# T-SQL Database Backup Cleanup Script logging of files to be deleted before delete

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I was having issues with the SQL maintanence plan cleanup task not deleting one particularly large database backup each night, it works for days then fails then starts working again and it always works correctly on the small databases.

I researched this maintanence plan cleanup task issue and tried everything I could think of to get it working, changed extension matching to *, added a \ at the end of folder path, changed age no NONE so all files would be deleted regardless of age, and still sometimes this backup is not getting deleted.

So I implemented this SQL JOB using the script below to see if that would work, but the same issue again, intermittently the large backup file is not deleted, when I run the task manually it seems to always delete it.

My question here is, is there a way to firstly get a list of files that match the delete criteria and write them to a log file before actually attempting to delete the files, that way I could at least see if for some reason the large backup file is not matching the criteria to be deleted in the first place.

Any assistance to otherwise delete the old backup files using T-SQL without using xp_cmdshell and without using a batch or powershell script would be appreciated.

```
declare @dt datetime
select @dt=dateadd(hh,-22,getdate())
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_delete_file 0,N'Z:\SQLBackups\',N'BAK',@dt,1
```

The version of SQL server I'm having the issue with:

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.4042.0

Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 10.50.4042.0

Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514

Microsoft MSXML 3.0 6.0

Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.10.9200.17609

Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0.50727.5485

Operating System 6.1.7601

Answer (score 0):

After creating a powershell script to delete the files and finding the error "Another process is using the file" I made this script to check what process that is using the handle64.exe program and found it was the Commvault agent CLBackup.exe that was locking the file.

Backup schedule conflict is the cause of the issue.

```
$log = ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).TrimEnd("ps1") + "log"
$handlelog = ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).TrimEnd(".ps1") + "-Handle.log"
$1 = gci 'Z:\SQLBackups' | %{gci $_.fullname -Filter '*.BAK' | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -le (get-date).addhours(-22)}}
write-output "$(get-date -format g) Files will be deleted: $1" >> $log
$1 | % {remove-item $_.fullname -force -Confirm:$FALSE}
if (!!($error)) {
write-output "$(get-date -format g) Open Handles on .BAK files:" >> $handlelog
$exec = "$env:SystemRoot\system32\cmd.exe /c" + (Split-Path($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)) + "\handle64.exe .BAK -u -nobanner -accepteula"
Invoke-Expression -Command:$exec >> $handlelog
$error >> $log
}
```